# How to pivot my dataframe into unique column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

This is an example of a bigger dataframe. It has two columns like this:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({"a":["zone 1", "zone 2", "code", "ID", np.nan, "zone 1", "zone 2", "code", "ID", "OBS"],
                    "b":["aaa", "bbb", 31, 10, np.nan, "ddd", "ggg", 23, 8, "NO INFO"]})

test
Out[9]: 
        a        b
0  zone 1      aaa
1  zone 2      bbb
2    code       31
3      ID       10
4     NaN      NaN
5  zone 1      ddd
6  zone 2      ggg
7    code       23
8      ID        8
9     OBS  NO INFO
```

I would like to convert the values from test["a"] to column headers and then the occurrences from test["b"] would be the real values for this dataframe. And for duplicated values in test["a"], I would have only one column name (no duplicates). The final result should be like this:

```
  zone 1 zone 2  code  ID  nan      OBS
0    aaa    bbb    31  10  NaN      NaN
1    ddd    ggg    23   8  NaN  NO INFO
```

I tried to use `df_pivot = test.pivot(columns="a", values="b")`, but it didn't work as I expected. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
test["idx"] = test["a"].eq("zone 1").cumsum()
out = test.pivot(index="idx", columns="a", values="b").reset_index(drop=True)
out.columns.name, out.index.name = None, None

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   NaN  ID      OBS code zone 1 zone 2
0  NaN  10      NaN   31    aaa    bbb
1  NaN   8  NO INFO   23    ddd    ggg
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at transpose()?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Original dataframe

test = pd.DataFrame({"a":["zone 1", "zone 2", "code", "ID", np.nan, "zone 1", "zone 2", "code", "ID", "OBS"],
                    "b":["aaa", "bbb", 31, 10, np.nan, "ddd", "ggg", 23, 8, "NO INFO"]})

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(test)

test_T = test.transpose()
print(test_T)
```

Prints

```
        0       1     2   3    4       5       6     7   8        9
a  zone 1  zone 2  code  ID  NaN  zone 1  zone 2  code  ID      OBS
b     aaa     bbb    31  10  NaN     ddd     ggg    23   8  NO INFO
```